# Show that the function $A →\|A\|$ defined by $\sup \|Ax\|/\|x\|$ is a norm in the space $M_n$ of $n\times n$ matrices with real entries

Tags: matrices, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

> Show that the function $A →\|A\|$ defined by $\sup \|Ax\|/\|x\|$ is a norm in the space $M_n$ of $n \times n$ matrices with real entries.

Definition 1.26. Let $X$ be a linear space (over $R$). A function $\|.\|$ is said to be a norm in $X$ if:
a) $\|x\| = 0$ if and only if $x = 0$;
b) $\|λx\| = |λ|\,\|x\|$ for every $λ ∈ R$ and $x ∈ X$;
c) $\|x + y\| \le \|x\| + \|y\|$ for every $x,y ∈ X$.

Exercise 1.12 from the book [http://www.amazon.com/Ordinary-Differential-Equations-Qualitative-Mathematics/dp/0821887491](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821887491)

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: For further reference, this is called the *operator norm*.

Answer (score 1):

To make the following argument clearer, I will denote the operator norm as $\|~\|_{op}$ and the vector norm as $\|~\|_{vec}$.

The question was to show that $\|A\|_{op}:=\sup\limits_{x\neq 0} \dfrac{\|Ax\|_{vec}}{\|x\|_{vec}}$ is indeed a norm given that $\|~\|_{vec}$ is a norm.

> The only element whose norm is zero should be the zero element.  All other elements should have positive norm.  I.e. $\|A\|_{op}\geq 0$ with equality if and only if $A=0$.

Suppose that $A=0$, the zero matrix.  Then $\|A\|_{op}=\sup\limits_{x\neq 0}\dfrac{\|Ax\|_{vec}}{\|x\|_{vec}}=\sup\limits_{x\neq 0}\dfrac{\|0\|_{vec}}{\|x\|_{vec}}=0$.  Remember that $\|~\|_{vec}$ is already known to be a norm, so the top of the fraction always equates to zero while the bottom of the fraction is nonzero.

Now, suppose that $A\neq 0$.  Then there is some $y\in Range(A)$ with a preimage $x'$ such that $Ax'=y\neq 0$.  This implies that $\|A\|_{op}=\sup\limits_{x\neq 0}\dfrac{\|Ax\|_{vec}}{\|x\|_{vec}}\geq\dfrac{\|Ax'\|_{vec}}{\|x'\|_{vec}}>0$ since $\|y\|_{vec}>0$ and $\|x'\|_{vec}>0$.  Again, remember that $\|~\|_{vec}$ is already known to be a norm.

> Norms of scalar multiples of elements should be scalar multiples of norms.  I.e. we wish to show $\|\lambda A\|_{op} = |\lambda|\|A\|_{op}$

We have simply $\|\lambda A\|_{op}=\sup\limits_{x\neq 0}\dfrac{\|\lambda Ax\|_{vec}}{\|x\|_{vec}}=\sup\limits_{x\neq 0}\dfrac{|\lambda|\|Ax\|_{vec}}{\|x\|_{vec}}=|\lambda|\sup\limits_{x\neq 0}\dfrac{\|Ax\|_{vec}}{\|x\|_{vec}}=|\lambda|\|A\|_{op}$

Again, remembering that $\|~\|_{vec}$ is already a norm.

> The norm of the sum of elements is less than or equal to the sum of the norms of elements.  I.e. we wish to show $\|A+B\|_{op}\leq \|A\|_{op}+\|B\|_{op}$

This, I will leave as an exercise for you to complete, but it will again rely on the fact that $\|~\|_{vec}$ is already known to be a norm.